# Command lind to recreate versions in Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

If I'm adding a new version in carrierwave, what is the command line to recreate the images if I already have existing images?

What would it be for localhost and for production if I'm using Heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to resize existing images.

You have to add you new version to the image uploader(taking 200*200 `thumb` as an example)

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
end
```

Then recreate them in console (taking `avatar` in `User` model as an example):

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.avatar.recreate_versions!
end
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to use a custom `rake` task, you can create a file `lib/tasks/resize_image.rake` and put the following code in this file:

```
namespace :resize_image do
  desc "RESIZE"
  task :recreate => :environment do
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.avatar.recreate_versions!
    end
  end
end
```

And in your console use:

```
rake resize_image:recreate
```